# pm2 status sometimes does not show the details like restart, uptime

Tags: pm2

I don't know why this happens. I always want to see the detailed report, but sometimes I get the smaller report version, sometimes the bigger one, why?

How can I set this up so I only get the detailed pm2 status?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is funny.

If the terminal window is small, `pm2 status` shows the lite version. If terminal windows is large, it shows the more detailed version.

Comment: Is there a way to see the lite version even when my window is big? pm2 makes estimation error sometimes and gives me the full version even when my window isn't wide enough. Things get printed to the next line and positions get messed up